# How can I underline a databound value from a DataTemplate?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, xaml, .net-3.5

If I want to display an underlined value in a TextBlock, I have to use a Run element. (If there's a better/easier way, I'd love to hear about it.)

```
<TextBlock>
  <Run TextDecorations="Underline" Text="MyText" />
</TextBlock>
```

Ideally, to implement this within a DataTemplate, it would look something like this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="underlineTemplate">
  <TextBlock>
    <Run TextDecorations="Underline" Text="{Binding Value}" />
  </TextBlock>
</DataTemplate>
```

This won't work, however, because the Run's Text property isn't a DependencyProperty, so you can't databind to it. Does anyone know how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TextDecoration is an attached property so it can be applied to the TextBlock also.  You create some pretty cool effects by templating the TextDecorations property.

See this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.textdecorations.underline.aspx).

```
<TextBlock TextDecorations="Underline" Text="{Binding Value}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
<TextBlock Text="MyText" TextDecorations="Underline" />
```